# How does setting preProcess argument in train function in Caret work?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am trying to predict the times table training a neural network. However, I couldn't really get how `preProcess` argument works in `train` function in Caret.

[In the docs](https://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#pp), it says:

> The preProcess class can be used for many operations on predictors, including centering and scaling.

When we set `preProcess` like below,

```r
tt.cv <- train(product ~ .,
               data = tt.train,
               method = 'neuralnet',
               tuneGrid = tune.grid,
               trControl = train.control,
               linear.output = TRUE,
               algorithm = 'backprop',
               preProcess = 'range',
               learningrate = 0.01)
```

1. Does it mean that the `train` function preprocesses (normalizes) the training data passed, in this case `tt.train`?
2. After the training is done, when we are trying to `predict`, do we pass normalized inputs to the `predict` function or are inputs normalized in the function because we set the `preProcess` parameter?

```r
# Do we do
predict(tt.cv, tt.test)
# or
predict(tt.cv, tt.normalized.test)
```

3. And from the quote above, it seems that when we use `preProcess`, outputs are not normalized this way in training, how do we go about normalizing outputs? Or do we just normalize the training data beforehand like below and then pass it to the `train` function?

```r
preProc <- preProcess(tt, method = 'range')
tt.preProcessed <- predict(preProc, tt)
tt.preProcessed.train <- tt.preProcessed[indexes,]
tt.preProcessed.test <- tt.preProcessed[-indexes,]
```

The whole code:

```r
library(caret)
library(neuralnet)

# Create the dataset
tt = data.frame(multiplier = rep(1:10, times = 10), multiplicand = rep(1:10, each = 10))
tt = cbind(tt, data.frame(product = tt$multiplier * tt$multiplicand))

# Splitting 
indexes = createDataPartition(tt$product,
                              times = 1,
                              p = 0.7,
                              list = FALSE)
tt.train = tt[indexes,]
tt.test = tt[-indexes,]

# Pre-process

preProc <- preProcess(tt, method = c('center', 'scale'))
tt.preProcessed <- predict(preProc, tt)
tt.preProcessed.train <- tt.preProcessed[indexes,]
tt.preProcessed.test <- tt.preProcessed[-indexes,]

# Train

train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                              number = 10,
                              repeats = 3,
                              savePredictions = TRUE)

tune.grid <- expand.grid(layer1 = 8,
                         layer2 = 0,
                         layer3 = 0)

tt.cv <- train(product ~ .,
               data = tt.train,
               method = 'neuralnet',
               tuneGrid = tune.grid,
               trControl = train.control,
               algorithm = 'backprop',
               learningrate = 0.01,
               stepmax = 100000,
               preProcess = c('center', 'scale'),
               lifesign = 'minimal',
               threshold = 0.01)
```

Comment: The question would benefit from a reproducible example. In fact I suspect that reproducible example would answer your questions. In short pre-processing all the train data before cross validation causes data leakage and thus optimistic bias in performance estimation. So one should pre-process within each training instance during cross validation (use `preProc` argument of train) . Caret takes care of all transformations if you applied it this way.

Comment: Sure I can add an example. Actually what I want to know is, when I set the `preProcess` argument of train function, do outputs get normalized as well in the training data passed?

Comment: When I just use `preProcess` argument in `train` function and pass the training data without any normalization, then I get algorithm did not converge errors. I will add my code in the question.

Comment: I trust this fails for you since the neural network does not like un-scaled outcomes. One way to perform centering and scaling of both predictors and outcomes is to use `recipes` package. Using something like `rec_reg <- recipe(product ~ ., data = tt.train) %>%
  step_center(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_scale(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_center(all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_scale(all_outcomes())`. If you cant make it work, post as comment and I will provide an answer.

Comment: This worked as well. But I wonder, what is the difference between first normalizing the data and then passing it to the train function, and passing a recipe and the training data without normalization to the train function?

Comment: I've actually tried both and what I get is similar so what causes the difference? I've `set.seed(12)` and run the code for the two cases I've explained above. For the first case I got: `RMSE = 0.03182556`, `Rsquared = 0.9989082`, `MAE = 0.0245833` and for the second case I got `RMSE = 0.03195398`, `Rsquared = 0.9989854`, `MAE = 0.02482346`

Comment: [read this](https://medium.com/@ODSC/how-to-fix-data-leakage-your-models-greatest-enemy-e34fa26abac5). When you use `recipes`in each training instance of CV the train data is normalized and then the mean and standard deviation obtained this way is used to process the test fold data before prediction.

Comment: By the way, is there a function to make a prediction that will give me the mapped result? I mean when I use `predict.train()` it returns the normalized predictions, how would I get it in the range of `[1, 100]` which is my output domain from times table.

Comment: You can use the info stored in the recipe: `preds <- predict(tt.cv, tt.test); preds * tt.cv$recipe$steps[[4]]$sds + tt.cv$recipe$steps[[3]]$means`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but shouldn't I multiply the `preds` with the `product` sds? I mean `tt.cv$recipe$steps[[2]]$sds`

Comment: Okay that was my mistake sorry. I got the order wrong in the recipe.